# Can't Connect to MySql From Rails Application in Windows

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, windows

I am trying to create a Rails application in windows with MySQL as the Database. I have created a rails app and it runs just as fine. But when I try to connect to the mySQL database I am getting weird errors, which I was unable to solve after hours of Googling and hunting around. Maybe I am performing a silly mistake, new to Rails and Ruby.

Here is how I proceeded in creating the app with MYSQL

1. In command prompt

   rails new sample_app -d mysql

[success]

1. Opened a new command prompt window and

   C:\sites\cd sample_app> rails -s

Now I get this error

```
Could not find gem mysq12 (>=0) in any of the gem sources listed in your Gemfile
Run bundle install to install missing gems
```

Note: I didn't get the error when I created my first rails app without using Mysql.

1. Next, I ran this command

   gem install mysql2

And got this

```
Temporarily enhancing PATH to include DevKit...
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing mysql2:
ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.8.7/bin/ruby.exe extconf.rb
checking for rb_thread_blocking_region()... no
checking for rb_wait_for_single_fd()... no
checking for rb_hash_dup()... no
checking for rb_intern3()... no
*** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of
necessary libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more
details.  You may need configuration options.
```

1. Next I ran this one -

   bundle install
2. Closed all command prompt windows, opened a new one, moved to my app directory and typed

   rails -s

Error:

```
could not find gem mysq12 (>=0) in any of the gem sources listed in your Gemfile

Run bundle install to install missing gems
```

Here are some information which I think will be useful

```
- Rails 3.0.9
- Ruby 1.8.7
- rake (10.1.0, 0.8.7)
- mysql (2.9.1 x86-mingw32)
- MySql 5.6 installed and running (I have created a DB and tables)
- OS: Windows 7 64bit
```

Here is how my database.yaml file looks like:

```
development:
adapter: mysql2
encoding: utf8
reconnect: false
database: sample_app_development
pool: 5
username: root
password: buiskol
host: localhost
```

Here is how the gemfile of the app looks like

```
source 'http://rubygems.org'

gem 'rails', '3.0.9'

# Bundle edge Rails instead:
# gem 'rails', :git => 'git://github.com/rails/rails.git'

gem 'mysql2', '~> 2.9.1'
```

I think the problem is that my mysql2 gem is not properly installed. I am not sure where I am doing the mistake. Any help will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Why are you using gem 'mysql2', '~> 2.9.1' instead of gem "mysql2", "~> 0.3.13"? According to [this](http://rubygems.org/gems/mysql2/versions), there isn't any 2.9.1 version, maybe you meant 0.2.9 ? Otherwise, you're installing the wrong version of that gem, or the wrong gem with the right version.

You should use:

```
gem "mysql", "~> 2.9.1"
```

or

```
gem "mysql2", "~> 0.3.13"
```

in your gem file. Since there's no version 2.9.1 for mysql2, correct the typo and try again